# How do I determine whether a NSTextView is scrolled to the button in Swift?

Tags: swift, nstextview, nsscrollview

How do I determine whether a `NSTextView` is scrolled to the buttom?

I'm making an IRC-ish chat app. The app appends new messages to a `NSTextView` and then scrolls the view to the button.

I want to disable the automatic down scrolling when said `NSTextView` isn't scrolled to the button, because it indicates that the user is scrolling up to read previous messages. I hope it makes sense. When appending new messages I need some way to check whether the `NSTextView` is scrolled to the button.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Well, turned out to be very easy. Assuming your NSTextView is "embedded" in a NSScrollView:

```
    if textView.visibleRect.maxY == textView.frame.maxY {
        print("YUP!")
    } else {
        print("NOPE!")
    }
```

Comment: Instead of appending many different text parts to a single text view, you should have like a table view  (or collection view) of messages, each message being in its own text view. You would then benefit from the table view methods to manage and find specific rows and their positions in the timeline.

Comment: Thanks, but tableviews are not really suitable for this type of application. But I am using a tableview for a list of users, though :D